# I get 404 error in google webmaster from unknown php page

Tags: 404, crawl-errors

In my wallpaper website that i code myself in php.There i get 404 error in google crawling.These errors are from unknow page like

> details.php?image_id=121&sessionid=55fc9acb0d1b324897db6da3163f11f7

I have no page with name details.php

Comment: Did you click on the reported error?  Google will tell you where it is finding the link.   It may even be from an external website.

Comment: 404 errors are not a problem unless you created the link yourself. Do not worry too much about 404 errors from links on another site. Do not mark them as fixed if the link is to a non-existing page. Just leave it alone and do not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

404 errors occur all the time and there is no need to be concerned. The only time that you really need to do anything is if the 404 error is for a page that is meant to be there in which case you need to find where it went, but for random pages like that which have never existed there is no need to worry you can safely ignore it, it won't affect your server or your SERP rankings at all.